# how to re render a list after updating an array state in a position in between (not at top or bottom in the list)?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, drag-and-drop, react-state

I have an html list and I interchange the list items (reactjs state). After interchanging items, How could I do to re render the list items if I erase an item in between (actually I delete the item correctly in the state but can't be shwon right in the list)?

State:  items is an array. Array position can be different to each item position state value (see object).

List: List position is the position of each item, i.e. object value, but can be different compared to the array index of the object.

Interchange items: changing inner html of each list item involved by using drag and drop.

Erase: When I erase a recently interchanged item that is in between, it's erase the last list item, althoug it does not include the item in array state that was deleted (changes in array state are well, just the graphic interface shows the problem).

My state:

```
this.state = {
            items:[{item:"", position: 0}],
            type: "text"
        };
```

My Drop function when I exchange items by changing inner HTML of each list item:

```
drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let dropId = event.target.id;
        let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        if(data != dropId){

            //  Changing list items positions
            let dropSpace = document.getElementById(dropId);
            let dataSpace = document.getElementById(data);
            if (dropSpace === null){
                console.log("wrong zone");
                return -1;
            }
            dropSpace.classList.remove('over');
            let auxInner = dropSpace.innerHTML;
            console.log(dropSpace);
            console.log(dataSpace);
            console.log(auxInner);
            dropSpace.innerHTML = dataSpace.innerHTML;
            dataSpace.innerHTML = auxInner;

            // dropSpace.setAttribute("id", data);
            // dataSpace.setAttribute("id", dropId);

            //  Position update
            let idx = parseInt(data.substr(data.length - 1));
            let position = parseInt(dropId.substr(dropId.length - 1));
            let iArray = this.state.items;

            iArray[iArray.findIndex(item => item.position === idx)].position = position;
            iArray[iArray.findIndex(item => item.position === position)].position = idx;
            // iArray[idx].position = position;
            // iArray[position].position = idx;
            console.log(iArray);

            //  Restaurating the events
            let but1 = document.getElementById("erase"+idx);
            but1.addEventListener("click", this.eraseItem);
            let but2 = document.getElementById("erase"+position);
            but2.addEventListener("click", this.eraseItem);

            this.setState({
                items: iArray
            });
        }

        //  Avoid changing the type of input (anti-fail system :) )
        let typeElement = document.getElementById("item-type");
        typeElement.disabled = true;
    }
```

My erase function:

```
eraseItem(event){
        let targetId = event.target.id;
        // let element = document.getElementById(targetId);
        // let parent = element.parentNode;
        // parent.innerHTML = "";
        // console.log(targetId);
        let idx = parseInt(targetId.substr(targetId.length - 1));
        let iArray = this.state.items;
        // iArray.splice(iArray.findIndex(item => item.position === idx), 1);
        let erasen = iArray.splice(idx, 1);
        iArray.map((item) =>{
            if(item.position >= erasen[0].position){
                let pos = item.position;
                item.position = pos - 1;
            }
        });
        console.log(erasen[0]);
        console.log(iArray);
        this.setState({
            items: iArray
        });
    }
```

And the content of my react component when I use those function and th state as props:

```
<ul id="item-zone"
                    className="ul-items">
                    {
                        this.props.items.map((item, idx)=> {
                            return (
                                <li id={"container"+idx}
                                    onDragStart={this.props.drag}
                                    onDrop={this.props.drop}
                                    onDragOver={this.props.allowDrop}
                                    onDragEnter={this.props.dragEnter}
                                    onDragLeave={this.props.dragLeave}
                                    className="dad"
                                    draggable="true"
                                    key={idx}>
                                    <Button className={"questionErase set-left showErase"}
                                            id={"erase"+idx}
                                            draggable="false"
                                            onClick={this.props.eraseItem} block>
                                        <Glyphicon glyph="trash" id={"erase"+idx} />
                                    </Button>
                                    <div className={this.props.type === "text" ? "showDiv":"hiddenDiv"}
                                         draggable="false">
                                        <FieldGroup
                                            id={'itemText'+idx}
                                            type='text'
                                            name={'itemText'+idx}
                                            className="set-right itemButton"
                                            placeholder='Write Item'
                                            value={item.item}
                                            onChange={this.props.changeField}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={this.props.type === "image" ? "showDiv":"hiddenDiv"}
                                         draggable="false">
                                        <FieldGroup
                                            id={'itemUrl'+idx}
                                            type='url'
                                            name={'itemUrl'+idx}
                                            className="set-right itemButton"
                                            placeholder='Write Item Url'
                                            value={item.item}
                                            onChange={this.props.changeField}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
```

Result now:

- I exchange items correctly, but when erasing an item in between (e.g. position 2 in the list) after an interchange, just erase the last list item while showing wrong information in the position 2 (for this example). Data in state is well according to developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Today I could solve the problem as next:

Problem: wrong understanding of reactjs states. When changing html that contents an state is not the right way to change the position of an item in an array and a list at the same time.

Answer: I did interchange the items by "updating" the innerHTML of each list item. So, you can avoid that process and instead just update the array index of the object in the state and it automatically is gonna change the position of your object/item in the array and also in the GUI (list in html). (See changes after the comment: "Array index of items updated", in the code.

Note: Do not interchange innerHTML content among the list items when using react states, because you'll have problems when updating/deleting an item of that react state. Instead OF this, you should change the position in the array state and React will do the changes in the view for you.

```
    drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let dropId = event.target.id;
        let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        if(data != dropId){

            //  Changing list items positions
            let dropSpace = document.getElementById(dropId);
            dropSpace.classList.remove('over');
            // this.positionUpdate(dropId, data);

            //  Position update
            let idx = parseInt(data.substr(data.length - 1));
            let position = parseInt(dropId.substr(dropId.length - 1));
            let iArray = this.state.items;

            //  Array shifting values utilities (saving indexes)
            let arrayIdx = iArray.findIndex(item => item.position === idx);
            let arrayPosition = iArray.findIndex(item => item.position === position);

            //  Array item position value updating
            iArray[arrayIdx].position = position;
            iArray[arrayPosition].position = idx;

            //  Array index of items updated
            let aux = iArray[arrayPosition];
            iArray[arrayPosition] = iArray[arrayIdx];
            iArray[arrayIdx] = aux;
            console.log(iArray);

            this.setState({
                items: iArray
            });
        }

        //  Avoid changing the type of input (anti-fail system :) )
        let typeElement = document.getElementById("item-type");
        typeElement.disabled = true;
    }
```

And problem solved!